# No remote commands executed when ssh runs as sudo

Tags: linux, ssh, sudo

The following command gives the expected result (file is created):

```
sshpass -p pas ssh root@host 'touch foo'
```

But the following one does nothing on the remote host:

```
sudo sshpass -p pas ssh root@host 'touch foo'
```

The only difference here is just `sudo` mode.

What is the reason here? And how this can be solved?

Comment: It should work, post output of `echo $?` after running the command.

Comment: first command gives me 0, but second gives no output

Comment: Not possible, run it and then run `echo $?` as the very next command.

Comment: same thing, what I noticed is that first command execution takes more time than second.. maybe I can try some verbose mode?

Comment: You can try learning how to run `echo $?`.

Comment: Found a problem, posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is more visible when running `ssh -v`.

With `sudo` communication interrupts after detecting the server host key.

To solve the problem `ssh` needs to run with the following argument `-o "StrictHostKeyChecking no"`.